# NodeJs express4-tedious - Stored Procedure for SELECT to return response as JSON

Tags: node.js, sql-server, tedious

Couldn't show the response in JSON while using stored procedure.

I'm using express4-tedious to fetch results. It works fine if I use the select query but if I use the same with the stored procedure I don't know how to bind it in JSON.

The response screen is blank as I couldn't get the results.

```
var tediousExpress = require('express4-tedious');
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
    req.sql("exec GETDataOfEmployee @id")
    .param('id', req.params.id, TYPES.VarChar)
    .exec(res)
});
```

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would use:

```js
var tediousExpress = require('express4-tedious');
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {

    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    req.sql("exec GETDataOfEmployee @id")
    .param('id', req.params.id, TYPES.VarChar)
    .into(res, '{}')
});
```

Do you have the this at the end of your SQL query in your stored procedure?:

```
for json path, without_array_wrapper
```